# Send push notification title to its invocation intent in Actions on Google

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm sending push notifications in Actions on Google (ref [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications)).

So once I send the notification I'm sending `title` in it. So it looks like this, where `A Very Happy Birthday, Jay Patel` is the title that I've sent.

[image]

So once I click on the notification, it opens Google Assistant and invokes the intent (configured [in this step](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#console_setup)), but it doesn't specify any contexts or other data regarding that notification so I'm not getting a person name that I've specified in `title` or any other data.

> **I want to know, is there anyway so that I can pass some data(title or any other data of notification) to the invocation intent when a
>   person taps on the notification?**

I'm getting this json response in my webhook when a person taps on the notification

```
    {  
   "responseId":"e2de9045-b415-kr45-be96-1a35779abcde",
   "queryResult":{  
      "queryText":"intent:send_push",
      "parameters":{  

      },
      "allRequiredParamsPresent":true,
      "fulfillmentText":"Latest update is here!",
      "fulfillmentMessages":[  
         {  
            "text":{  
               "text":[  
                  "Latest update is here!"
               ]
            }
         }
      ],
      "intent":{  
         "name":"projects/happierwork-bot/agent/intents/d1f4c032-28cf-4906-a393-6f2a612c0496",
         "displayName":"send_push"
      },
      "intentDetectionConfidence":1.0,
      "languageCode":"en-in"
   },
   "originalDetectIntentRequest":{  
      "source":"google",
      "version":"2",
      "payload":{  
         "user":{  
            "userId":"my_id",
            "accessToken":"my_token",
            "permissions":[  
               "UPDATE"
            ],
            "locale":"en-IN",
            "lastSeen":"2018-10-09T05:57:18Z"
         },
         "conversation":{  
            "conversationId":"ABwppHE7XKXDdjfjSRPF_OCVttGKMavfasdffngesQEI2Jy11Q8fp8lNXgpgGtFe7KCxK3WWey-1ColL7",
            "type":"NEW"
         },
         "inputs":[  
            {  
               "intent":"send_push",
               "rawInputs":[  
                  {  
                     "inputType":"URL",
                     "url":"bot_url?intent=send_push"
                  }
               ],
               "arguments":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"UPDATES",
                     "boolValue":true
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "surface":{  
            "capabilities":[  
               {  
                  "name":"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
               }
            ]
         },
         "isInSandbox":true,
         "availableSurfaces":[  
            {  
               "capabilities":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "session":"projects/myproject-bot/agent/sessions/ABwppHE7XKXDdjfjSRPF_OCVtasdffagbKiGKA9sCsQEI2Jy11Q8fp8lNXgpgGtFe7KCxK3WWey-1ColL7"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply argument data using the argument field of the push message target.

Please view the reference for more detail:
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.12.0/interfaces/_service_actionssdk_api_v2_.googleactionsv2custompushmessagetarget.html

Comment: Does any documentation on this exist? I have had success passing one type of argument (one that was named similarly to a parameter setup in Dialogflow), but I can't get it to send a different argument. I am wondering if there are length restrictions on the arguments, or similar?