# How to send and receive argument via push-notification using Google DialogFlow/Actions?

Tags: push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to pass a argument/parameter in a push notification using DialogFlow/Google Actions and receive the value of the argument in the target intent, that was declared in the custom push message.

What is the correct way to pass a parameter/object in the custom push message and how can I receive the paramter in the target intent.

Here is my programming code what I've already tried. Here I use argumet and corresponding key-value pairs. Is this the correct way? Can I also pass complex objects? How?

```
customPushMessage: {
    userNotification: {
        title: 'Das ist der Titel unserer Notification',
    },
    target: {
        userId: userId,
        intent: 'ProductFinderShoppingBasketIntent',
        argument: {
            'rawText': 'Target Argument Raw Text',
            'textValue': 'Target Argument Text Value',
            'name': 'Target Argument Name',
        },
        locale: locale,
    },
},
```

Here is an extract of the implementation of the target intent that opens when the user clicks on the notification. This is how I try to receive and read the passed parameter value:

```
productId = conv.arguments.get('textValue') as string
```

How to receive it correctly? Can someone give a short code samply, also for the custom push message?

Comment: There's no way to pass custom data in a notification.

Comment: @NickFelker what about what is written in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714377/send-push-notification-title-to-its-invocation-intent-in-actions-on-google ?

I have noticed that if I send an argument which is named the same as a parameter in Dialogflow to the notification, it does indeed send it to the fulfillment with the right parameter value - however I have only been able to make it work with one argument with very simple string data.

How come it's not possible, it seems like an essential feature, and one that Google Assistant itself uses a lot?